# Jquery return from nested function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Here is my code

```
 <input type="file" id="choose" multiple="multiple" />
<br>
<div id="uploadPreview"></div>



function readImage(file) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var image  = new Image();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
    reader.onload = function(_file) {
        image.src    = _file.target.result;              // url.createObjectURL(file);
        image.onload = function() {
            var w = this.width,
                h = this.height,
                t = file.type,                           // ext only: // file.type.split('/')[1],
                n = file.name;
             if (h < 400 || w < 400) {
                 alert('in');
                    return true;
                }
        };

    };

}
$("#choose").change(function (e) {

    var F = this.files;
    alert( readImage( F[0]) );
});
```

when I upload low image, it always returns undefined

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mparvez1986/rq8nA/56/)

Comment: You can't return like that since `the onload is execured asynchornously

Comment: What could be a possible solution then?

Comment: you should use a callback

Comment: can you please give any sample code, or just update my fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4zs7pbbr/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can get returned value like this

```
function readImage(file, callback) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var image  = new Image();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
    reader.onload = function(_file) {
        image.src    = _file.target.result;              // url.createObjectURL(file);
        image.onload = function() {
            var w = this.width,
                h = this.height,
                t = file.type,                           // ext only: // file.type.split('/')[1],
                n = file.name;
             if (h < 400 || w < 400) {
                 alert('in');
                    callback(true);
                }
        };

    };

}


$("#choose").change(function (e) {

    var F = this.files;
    readImage( F[0], function(value){
        alert( value );
    });
});
```